# Scale image inside a fixed div with different formats

Tags: css, image, scale

I need a way to ajust the height OR width of an image inside a div with a fixed height and width. The properties should be scaled automaticly.

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;">
    <img style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;" src="..." />
</div>
```

this works only with square images. however, the images can be transversal and upright and should be automatically scaled to the available area. In addition, the embedded image should be aligned to the lower left.

whether a picture has high or landscape format should be determined automatically.

Is there an automatic calculation in CSS based on the pattern "max-width or max-height"?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you would benefit from background-size: contain

Comment: @JasonB I would not have thought that. sometimes it can be easy too. Thanks a lot!